# Feeding in Facebook API Error Code 191 - what I am doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, error-handling, feed

I just tried,read everything - but somehow I was still not able to manage this problem.
Does anyone have a clue ?

For details look here :
http://i1145.photobucket.com/albums/o501/King_Coatie/notworking.gif

Comment: Try disabling the sandbox mode and see if that helps, also try removing app domains and try then. It might be one of those enigmatic sandbox "features". Also - I don't see your FB.init with your appID anywhere (on the javascript SDK end, not PHP).

Comment: Disabled Sandbox -> nothing changed ... Then I removed the app domains and add them again -> nothing changed ... added appID to my FB.Init -> and once more nothing changed ... error pops still up ... any other ideas ? :/

Answer (score 0):

Try loading and initializing the Javascript SDK like it's shown here:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
// init the FB JS SDK
FB.init({
  appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
  channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
  status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
  cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
  xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
});

// Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

};

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
(function(d, debug){
 var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
 ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document, /*debug*/ false));
</script>
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

You need to provide appID to the FB object for it to recognize which app it's dealing with.

Comment: Even after I changed the Init script and adding an app_id to my function postToFeed ... still got the same error :/

Comment: You need to provide appId to the init function, not your postToFeed function. Also make sure you're not calling the function before FB.init(). My best guess is that it's the FB.init() part. If that's not it, try replacing https with http in redirect_uri, as you're calling the non-secure Facebook SDK (http) and want it to open a secure redirect (https), that could be a conflict.